# Setting up proper expire header in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running apache2 on Ubuntu. I want to set expiration header like this.

```
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

I understang that it will cache a url like www.example.com/images/a.gif for one year.

My question is what about url like this. www.example.com/javascripts/all.js?123456 . Assuming that the above url is cached. Now if I change the url to www.example.com/javascripts/all.js?abcdef will browser request for new js file?

Basically I am trying to find while caching does browser take into account full url including the data after the question mark.

Also my current vhost configuration looks like this

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
  ServerName xxxx
  ServerAlias xxxxx
  DocumentRoot /home/xxx/current/public
  <Directory "/home/xxxx/current/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
  <Location />
    # Insert filter
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

  </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I am assuming that  I can put ExpiresActive On and other statements just before  tag begins.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok. According to your configuration all.js?123456 will request a new version of all.js . Also you can put ExpiresActiveOn inside a virtual host or directory .